# Implement continuous deployment to angular project using ftp

Tags: ftp, angular6, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I am completely new to CI CD. Now I was asked to implement it using bitbucket.

I am working on a angular project and my server is to be connected using FTP.

After many research I could write upto these lines in my yml file.

My server host name is XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
In the repository variable, 
I have given my FTP_HOST_PATH as ftp://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX/bak/testCI

```
image: trion/ng-cli

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: "Build, test & deploy to production"
          deployment: production
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - echo "$(ls -la dist/)"
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @angular/cli
            - npm run build:prod
            - ls -ltr
            - echo "Let's go in to our dist/ and initialize there with git"
            - apt-get update
            - apt-get -qq install git-ftp
            - git ftp init --username $FTP_USERNAME --password $FTP_PASSWORD $FTP_HOST_PATH
```

But this is getting me failed.

Comment: The definition of `git ftp init` is to upload all files for me you should use `git ftp push` instead. <br/>
Better to use the this three variable instead of --username etc  <br/>
git config git-ftp.url "$FTP_HOST_PATH"
git config git-ftp.user "$FTP"
git config git-ftp.password "$FTP_PASSWORD"

Copy the log error to help

Comment: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
Skipping cache upload for failed step
Searching for test report files in directories named [test-results, failsafe-reports, test-reports, surefire-reports] down to a depth of 4
Finished scanning for test reports. Found 0 test report files.
Merged test suites, total number tests is 0, with 0 failures and 0 errors.

Comment: Try to use `sudo apt-get `

Comment: Yes I have tried sudo as well

Comment: what about :
`sudo -i ` -

`rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*`  -

`exit` -

`sudo apt update`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your image to `node:x.x.x` and the script `git ftp init -u "$FTP_USERNAME" -p "$FTP_PASSWORD" ftp://$FTP_HOST_PATH` (with quotes).

Remeber, you will need to trigger `init` first time only, after, use `ftp push`